# Undefined method 'devise' when including User model outside Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, devise

I am developing an application that consists in two parts: A ruby command line application and a Rails application for the front-end.

I've been using ActiveRecord and the Rails models in the Ruby application by including them individually the following way:

```
Dir[File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../../RailsApp/app/models/*.rb'].each do |file|
  filename = File.basename(file, File.extname(file))
  require_relative "../../RailsApp/app/models/" + filename
end
```

And by manually mantaining two nearly identical Gemfile files for dependencies (an approach that I think is not the best)

Yesterday I added Devise to the Rails application, and now when the ruby app tries to include the user model, the message `undefined method devise for class <xxxxx>` appears.

I added the devise gem in my ruby app's Gemfile, but the error continues. If I understand correctly, Devise is a Rails Engine, which is why it's not being loaded just by requiring the gem.

I read that a better approach to include Rails models inside another application is by requiring the `environment.rb` file, but when I tried that, I got an error with ActionMailer:

```
undefined method `action_mailer' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration:0xbbb54bc>
```

How can I solve the issue with devise? Is there a better way to include Rails models inside another application than the one I'm currently using to avoid mantaining two gemfiles ? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even though this architecture must change in the near future, we managed to work around this error by including devise and its initializer in the ruby application.

```
# FIXME: Dependency needed in Rails but not in the engine.
require 'devise'
require_relative "../../RailsApp/config/initializers/devise.rb"

#Load all the models
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try putting `require 'devise'` before you call the models, but I'm not sure if that would work?

I agree that this general architecture feels wrong.

I would extract the code that is common to both applications to a separate library and then include that library in both applications. Your easiest bet to do this is to make your own library into a Gem and then include it both Gemfiles. The common gems will be specified in the shared library. Making Gems is really easy. Good instructions can be found at http://asciicasts.com/episodes/245-new-gem-with-bundler (or the associated Railscast).

Your command-line app probably shouldn't need to care about Devise. If you need a User model in both, you can just include it in the shared library and then add any extra functionality (such as Devise) in the Rails app.

Does that help?

Comment: Thank you for the response. We all agree that this kind of architecture must be changed in the near future for something more orthogonal. Upvote for the advice about moving the common functionality to a separate gem. For now I solved the issue by requiring devise and its initializer.

Answer (score 0):

You could move the time of loading your models into the parent app initialization step, rather than at the time your gem is loading itself.

Build a shared_code gem, as your other answer suggests.

Move your shared_code loading loop into an initializer file (such as require 'user')

List the gem dependencies (like devise) of your models in the shared_code gemspec.

In your shared_code gem, include a generator to install the initializer file into apps that use the shared_code gem.

Then to use your shared code in the parent app,

Gemfile:

```
gem 'shared_code'
```

console:

```
rails generate shared_code:install
```

This is the same pattern devise and other gems use to configure themselves at the correct time in the initialization sequence of the parent application.

If you use require_relative on the devise initializer in the user.rb file itself, within the shared_code gem, you are removing the possibility that two different parent applications that are using your shared_code might need to initialize devise (or another gem that both the app and your gem depend on) differently.

Details on the generator:

You can create the shared_code:install command by creating the generator like this:

lib/generators/shared_code/install_generator.rb

```
module SharedCode
  class InstallGenerator < Rails::Generators::Base
    source_root File.expand_path('../templates', __FILE__)
    def copy_initializer_file
      copy_file "shared_code.rb", "config/initializers/shared_code.rb"
    end
  end
end
```

Put your model load code into lib/generators/shared_code/templates/shared_code.rb