# Including Devise modules into a User model defined outside of Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, devise

I'm using Rails 2.3 and Devise 1.0.11. Please forgive any glaring mistakes as I'm new to Rails.

The User model is defined in a folder outside of Rails (named "Common") and it is shared between different components, Rails being one of them. I included the devise modules in the User model like so:

```
class User < ActiverRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation
end
```

From the Rails app, Devise works fine.

The problem is when I try to run rspec tests from the Common folder, I get `undefined method 'devise'`. I've already tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10656659/1943995) from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10654469/undefined-method-devise-when-including-user-model-outside-rails) but it did not work for me. I get `uninitialized constant ActionController`. And when I `require 'action_controller'` I get `uninitialized constant Rails`. I'm guessing it needs something from the Rails environment but not sure what exactly.

I also tried including devise modules through a `devise_extension.rb` file in `config/initializers` so that devise does not have to be called from Common at all.

```
    class User
      devise :database_authenticable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable
    end
```

This seems to do the trick until I call `:password` in a view and I get `undefined method 'password'` so clearly I'm missing something there as well.

Not sure where to go from here, but any help is appreciated.