# Devise gem not deploying on Heroku platform

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

After spending 2 days trying to deploy my Rails app on Heroku, I've decided to surrender and ask for some help here...

My problem is that I'm trying to deploy a Rails 4.0.4 application on Heroku platform (it's working fine in my local environment) but it fails when I try to deploy on the Heroku platform. It's like Heroku is not recognizing Devise 3.2.4 (or it is not compatible).

I always get the same message:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `devise' for User (call 'User.connection' to establish 
a connection):Class
```

Here is the output of the command `git push heroku master`

```
[jeffersonlsz@localhost showYourselfApp (master)]$ git push heroku master
Enter passphrase for key '/home/jeffersonlsz/.ssh/id_rsa': 
X11 forwarding request failed on channel 0
Fetching repository, done.
Counting objects: 62, done.
Compressing objects: 100% (35/35), done.
Writing objects: 100% (36/36), 4.30 KiB, done.
Total 36 (delta 25), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Ruby app detected
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.0.0
-----> Installing dependencies using 1.5.2
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
       Fetching additional metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
       Using i18n (0.6.9)
       Using rake (10.3.1)
       Using minitest (4.7.5)
       Using multi_json (1.10.0)
       Using thread_safe (0.3.3)
       Using builder (3.1.4)
       Using erubis (2.7.0)
       Using tzinfo (0.3.39)
       Using rack (1.5.2)
       Using polyglot (0.3.4)
       Using mime-types (1.25.1)
       Using activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.3)
       Using arel (4.0.2)
       Using coffee-script-source (1.7.0)
       Using sass (3.2.19)
       Using execjs (2.0.2)
       Using thor (0.19.1)
       Using hike (1.2.3)
       Using json (1.8.1)
       Using pg (0.15.1)
       Using bundler (1.5.2)
       Using tilt (1.4.1)
       Using rails_serve_static_assets (0.0.2)
       Using rails_stdout_logging (0.0.3)
       Using activesupport (4.0.4)
       Using treetop (1.4.15)
       Using rack-test (0.6.2)
       Using coffee-script (2.2.0)
       Using rdoc (4.1.1)
       Using uglifier (2.5.0)
       Using bootstrap-sass (2.3.2.0)
       Using sprockets (2.11.0)
       Using rails_12factor (0.0.2)
       Using activemodel (4.0.4)
       Using jbuilder (1.5.3)
       Using actionpack (4.0.4)
       Using mail (2.5.4)
       Using sdoc (0.4.0)
       Using activerecord (4.0.4)
       Using railties (4.0.4)
       Using sprockets-rails (2.0.1)
       Using actionmailer (4.0.4)
       Using coffee-rails (4.0.1)
       Using jquery-rails (3.1.0)
       Using sass-rails (4.0.3)
       Using rails (4.0.4)
       Using turbolinks (2.2.2)
       Installing orm_adapter (0.5.0)
       Installing warden (1.2.3)
       Installing bcrypt (3.1.7)
       Installing devise (3.2.4)
       Your bundle is complete!
       Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
       It was installed into ./vendor/bundle
       Bundle completed (12.69s)
       Cleaning up the bundler cache.
-----> Writing config/database.yml to read from DATABASE_URL
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       rake aborted!
       NoMethodError: undefined method `devise' for User (call 'User.connection' to establish a connection):Class
       /tmp/build_59a23f0f-d0e9-44ae-8fb5-c417d3b22c35/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:22:in `method_missing'
       /tmp/build_59a23f0f-d0e9-44ae-8fb5-c417d3b22c35/app/models/user.rb:4:in `<class:User>'
       /tmp/build_59a23f0f-d0e9-44ae-8fb5-c417d3b22c35/app/models/user.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
       /tmp/build_59a23f0f-d0e9-44ae-8fb5-c417d3b22c35/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
       /tmp/build_59a23f0f-d0e9-44ae-8fb5-c417d3b22c35/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in require'
       /tmp/build_59a23f0f-d0e9-44ae-8fb5-c417d3b22c35/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
       /tmp/build_59a23f0f-d0e9-44ae-8fb5-c417d3b22c35/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
       /tmp/build_59a23f0f-d0e9-44ae-8fb5-c417d3b22c35/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:330:in `require_or_load'
       /tmp/build_59a23f0f-d0e9-44ae-8fb5-c417d3b22c35/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:463:in `load_missing_constant'
       /tmp/build_59a23f0f-d0e9-44ae-8fb5-c417d3b22c35/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:184:in `const_missing'
       /tmp/build_59a23f0f-d0e9-44ae-8fb5-c417d3b22c35/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:226:in `const_get'
       /tmp/build_59a23f0f-d0e9-44ae-8fb5-c417d3b22c35/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:226:in `block in constantize'
       /tmp/build_59a23f0f-d0e9-44ae-8fb5-c417d3b22c35/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:224:in `each'
       /tmp/build_59a23f0f-d0e9-44ae-8fb5-c417d3b22c35/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:224:in `inject'
       /tmp/build_59a23f0f-d0e9-44ae-8fb5-c417d3b22c35/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:224:in `constantize'
       /tmp/build_59a23f0f-d0e9-44ae-8fb5-c417d3b22c35/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:535:in `get'
       /tmp/build_59a23f0f-d0e9-44ae-8fb5-c417d3b22c35/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:566:in `constantize'
       /tmp/build_59a23f0f-d0e9-44ae-8fb5-c417d3b22c35/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/devise-3.2.4/lib/devise.rb:297:in `get'
       /tmp/build_59a23f0f-d0e9-44ae-8fb5-c417d3b22c35/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/devise-3.2.4/lib/devise/mapping.rb:77:in `to'
       /tmp/build_59a23f0f-d0e9-44ae-8fb5-c417d3b22c35/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/devise-3.2.4/lib/devise/mapping.rb:72:in `modules'
       /tmp/build_59a23f0f-d0e9-44ae-8fb5-c417d3b22c35/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/devise-3.2.4/lib/devise/mapping.rb:89:in `routes'
       /tmp/build_59a23f0f-d0e9-44ae-8fb5-c417d3b22c35/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/devise-3.2.4/lib/devise/mapping.rb:156:in `default_used_route'
       /tmp/build_59a23f0f-d0e9-44ae-8fb5-c417d3b22c35/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/devise-3.2.4/lib/devise/mapping.rb:66:in `initialize'
       /tmp/build_59a23f0f-d0e9-44ae-8fb5-c417d3b22c35/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/devise-3.2.4/lib/devise.rb:331:in `new'
       /tmp/build_59a23f0f-d0e9-44ae-8fb5-c417d3b22c35/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/devise-3.2.4/lib/devise.rb:331:in `add_mapping'
       /tmp/build_59a23f0f-d0e9-44ae-8fb5-c417d3b22c35/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/devise-3.2.4/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:221:in `block in devise_for'
       /tmp/build_59a23f0f-d0e9-44ae-8fb5-c417d3b22c35/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/devise-3.2.4/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:220:in `each'
       /tmp/build_59a23f0f-d0e9-44ae-8fb5-c417d3b22c35/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/devise-3.2.4/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:220:in `devise_for'
       /tmp/build_59a23f0f-d0e9-44ae-8fb5-c417d3b22c35/config/routes.rb:4:in `block in <top (required)>'
       /tmp/build_59a23f0f-d0e9-44ae-8fb5-c417d3b22c35/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:335:in `instance_exec'
       /tmp/build_59a23f0f-d0e9-44ae-8fb5-c417d3b22c35/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:335:in `eval_block'
       /tmp/build_59a23f0f-d0e9-44ae-8fb5-c417d3b22c35/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:313:in `draw'
       /tmp/build_59a23f0f-d0e9-44ae-8fb5-c417d3b22c35/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
       /tmp/build_59a23f0f-d0e9-44ae-8fb5-c417d3b22c35/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load'
       /tmp/build_59a23f0f-d0e9-44ae-8fb5-c417d3b22c35/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `block in load'
       /tmp/build_59a23f0f-d0e9-44ae-8fb5-c417d3b22c35/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
       /tmp/build_59a23f0f-d0e9-44ae-8fb5-c417d3b22c35/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load'
       /tmp/build_59a23f0f-d0e9-44ae-8fb5-c417d3b22c35/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `block in load_paths'
       /tmp/build_59a23f0f-d0e9-44ae-8fb5-c417d3b22c35/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `each'
       /tmp/build_59a23f0f-d0e9-44ae-8fb5-c417d3b22c35/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `load_paths'
       /tmp/build_59a23f0f-d0e9-44ae-8fb5-c417d3b22c35/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:16:in `reload!'
       /tmp/build_59a23f0f-d0e9-44ae-8fb5-c417d3b22c35/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:26:in `block in updater'
       /tmp/build_59a23f0f-d0e9-44ae-8fb5-c417d3b22c35/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:75:in `call'
       /tmp/build_59a23f0f-d0e9-44ae-8fb5-c417d3b22c35/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:75:in `execute'
       /tmp/build_59a23f0f-d0e9-44ae-8fb5-c417d3b22c35/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:27:in `updater'
       /tmp/build_59a23f0f-d0e9-44ae-8fb5-c417d3b22c35/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:6:in `execute_if_updated'
       /tmp/build_59a23f0f-d0e9-44ae-8fb5-c417d3b22c35/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:69:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
       /tmp/build_59a23f0f-d0e9-44ae-8fb5-c417d3b22c35/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
       /tmp/build_59a23f0f-d0e9-44ae-8fb5-c417d3b22c35/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
       /tmp/build_59a23f0f-d0e9-44ae-8fb5-c417d3b22c35/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
       /tmp/build_59a23f0f-d0e9-44ae-8fb5-c417d3b22c35/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
       /tmp/build_59a23f0f-d0e9-44ae-8fb5-c417d3b22c35/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize!'
       /tmp/build_59a23f0f-d0e9-44ae-8fb5-c417d3b22c35/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
       /tmp/build_59a23f0f-d0e9-44ae-8fb5-c417d3b22c35/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
       /tmp/build_59a23f0f-d0e9-44ae-8fb5-c417d3b22c35/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
       /tmp/build_59a23f0f-d0e9-44ae-8fb5-c417d3b22c35/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in require'
       /tmp/build_59a23f0f-d0e9-44ae-8fb5-c417d3b22c35/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
       /tmp/build_59a23f0f-d0e9-44ae-8fb5-c417d3b22c35/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
       /tmp/build_59a23f0f-d0e9-44ae-8fb5-c417d3b22c35/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/application.rb:189:in `require_environment!'
       /tmp/build_59a23f0f-d0e9-44ae-8fb5-c417d3b22c35/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/application.rb:250:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
       /tmp/build_59a23f0f-d0e9-44ae-8fb5-c417d3b22c35/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.0.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:54:in `block (2 levels) in define'
       Tasks: TOP => environment
       (See full trace by running task with --trace)
 !
 !     Precompiling assets failed.
 !

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app

To git@heroku.com:gentle-escarpment-8370.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:gentle-escarpment-8370.git'
```

Here is my `Gemfile`:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


gem 'rails', '4.0.4'

gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.3.2.0'
gem 'sprockets', '2.11.0'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.2'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

gem 'devise'
gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
```

And finally, my `User` model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  has_many :experiences
end
```

I'm not an experienced developer in Ruby or Rails (I've been studying the framework for less than two months) but I suspect that Heroku platform is not compatible with Rails 4.0.4 or Devise 3.2.4.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: both Rails and devise versions you have should work with `heroku`. it is something else

Comment: i deployed application with same version of devise and rails without any problem.

try to run rake assets:precompile on you local machine and see if you won't be able to compile assets with the same error?

Comment: yes, do rake assets:precompile then push to github repo before you push to heroku master

Comment: Thats the problem. The command rake assets:precompile is working fine in my machine. But it just doesn't work when I try to deploy on Heroku.

Comment: now it's seems that you don't have devise gem bundled on heroku or something else went wrong. Try to comment devise method from user model or try deploy to another fresh heroku application ...?

Comment: Run `heroku run rake db:migrate`

Answer (score 0):

Have you ran the `devise`installer? [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10654469/undefined-method-devise-when-including-user-model-outside-rails) seems to think you've not got the `devise initializer` in your app

As per the [`Devise` installation docs](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#getting-started), have you done this:

```
rails generate devise:install
```

---

This would seem to be confirmed if you look at what the error will be:

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
```

This is in the `user` model - meaning the error you're getting is because of this line. The `undefined method` error means you've not got that part of your app loaded, either because the dependency (`gem`) is not installed, or you've not initialized it

Can you confirm you have `config/initializers/devise.rb` present?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have solved the problem but just in case you haven't, this might help. I had the same issue and my problem was that I had the ./config/initializers/devise.rb file in the .gitignore. You can try updating this file to solve the issue.